# How can I display the camera view in the main window in real time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, augmented-reality

I'm trying to make an augmented reality application with a waypoint structure, like Yelp, and I'm wondering how to set up my main view so that it displays the camera view on the whole screen. I've heard of using the UIImagePickerController Class, but I'm unsure how to manipulate the code so that it doesn't actually take a picture, but just stays in the view mode. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

You should just be able to create a UIImagePickerController and set sourceType to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, and then disable the camera controls using showsCameraControls.

Comment: but will that automatically disable "takePicture"?

Comment: I don't think that it does. You might have to implement your own instance of it and just make it do nothing. <-- Just a guess